# Should I use partial function for database calls

Tags: scala

As per my understanding, partial functions are functions that are defined for a subset of input values.
So should I use partial functions for DAO's. For example:

```
getUserById(userId: Long): User
```

There is always an input `userId` which does not exists in db. So can I say it is not defined. And lift it when I call this function.

If yes where do I stop. Should I use partial functions for all methods which are not defined, say for null.

Answer (score 3):

`PartialFunction` is used when function is undefined for some elements of input data (input data may be `Seq` etc.)

For your case `Option` is better choice: it says that return data may be absent:

```
getUserById(userId:Long):Option[User]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using partial functions at all, because scala makes it very easy to call a partial function as though it were a total function. Instead it's better to use a function that returns `Option` as @Sergey suggests; that way the "partial-ness" is always explicit.

Idiomatic scala does not use `null` so I wouldn't worry about methods which are not defined for null, but certainly it's worth returning `Option` for methods which are only defined for some of their possible input values. Better still, though, is to only accept suitable types as input. E.g. if you have a function that's only valid for non-empty lists, it should take (scalaz) `NonEmptyList` as input rather than `List`.